# Why am I not able to run my SQL file from command line?

Tags: python, mysql, cmd, command-line, subprocess

I'm able to manually import a MySQL schema from a `.sql` dump file into my database using the following process from `cmd`:

```
cd C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\tests\mysql # Go to directory where .sql file is

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe" -uroot -proot # Run MySQL

\. schema_belgarath_test_create.sql # Run SQL
```

I've been trying to automate this using `subprocess.run` using the following code:

```
mysql_exe = r'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe'
mysql_dump = r'C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\tests\mysql\schema_belgarath_test_create.sql'
args = [mysql_exe, '-uroot', '-proot', r' \. ' + mysql_dump]
subprocess.run(args)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1059 (42000): Identifier name ' \. c:\users\philip\onedrive\betting\capra\tennis\polgara\tests\mysql\schema_belgarath_test_create.s' is too long
```

To get around this I tried changing the directory using `cwd=`:

```
mysql_exe = r'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe'
mysql_dump_path = r'C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\tests\mysql'
belgarath_sql = 'schema_belgarath_test_create.sql'
args = [mysql_exe, '-uroot', '-proot', r' \. ' + belgarath_sql]
subprocess.run(args, cwd=mysql_dump_path)
```

However, I now get the following error:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database ' \. schema_belgarath_test_create.sql'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-e` before passing the command `\. file.sql`, and you need to use quotation marks for the command.

For example:

```
mysql.exe -uroot -proot -e "\. file.sql"
```

Therefore, you python code should be:

```
mysql_exe = r'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe'
mysql_dump = r'C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\tests\mysql\schema_belgarath_test_create.sql'
mysql_cmd = r'"\. {}"'.format(mysql_dump)
args = [mysql_exe, '-uroot', '-proot', '-e', mysql_cmd]
subprocess.run(args)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Didn't need the quotation marks in the end...

Comment: Quick related follow up... what would the syntax if I wanted to perform an import such as ```belgarath_test < C:\\Users\\Philip\\OneDrive\\Betting\\Capra\\Tennis\\polgara\\tests\\mysql\\bets_baseline.sql```? I've tried this after the ```-e``` but get ```ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\U'.```. Is it picking up the ```\U``` of ```\\Users```?

Comment: Posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942418/why-am-i-getting-error-1049-42000-unknown-database

Comment: @Jossy you can't use `<` this way with `subprocess`. You have to create an input stream for your process and feed it with the content of the file. That's why `-e` is easier

Comment: Thanks @Aziz. When you say input stream - does this mean adding everything to the SQL file? So in this case include the target database?

Comment: @Jossy: When you type something like this: `program < file`, the shell or command line will open `file`, and feed it to `program` as its input stream. This is handled by the command line or shell itself. So, in Python, you cannot use `subprocess.run(['program', '<', 'file'])`. You have to manually read `file` content and send it to `program`. This is why using `-e` for `mysql.exe` is easier